# Can i cache connection secret in ADF pipeline instead of hitting AKV from every activity

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-data-factory

Currently I am using parametrized linked service to connect to AKV and then retrieve the connection secret. But with many Pipelines and activities we are facing throttling issue on AKV side. We want to limit number of hots to AKV and cache/store the retrieved connection somewhere within ADF pipeline but I do not see any option to do so. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you can - I recently worked with a massive retail customer and they hit a similar issue so they used a Java cache class that cached the relevant data from AKV (it was a payment token) for 1hr and at the end of the hour it pulled the data in from AKV again. The cache time was configurable, they are not bound to 1hr.